# Multiple OS on same physical disk without dual boot loader

Tags: partitioning, bios, multi-boot, uefi

My HP ZBook 15 G3 allows boot options when I press the `F9` button. It lists my disks which are able to boot an OS. But one thing in particular caught my attention which is **Boot from file**. I can't find any information what this is and how can I use it? I'd love to have a dual boot system on my notebook without the actual dual boot loader.

Is it possible to have two (or more) OSes on the same physical disk without a dual boot loader to select the OS? Could I just have some sort of partitioning that I could use `F9` to select the OS I would want to boot into?

Or somehow employ this *Boot from file* option for this?

I would like to avoid the dual boot loader so that my machine when untouched on restart would boot the OEM Widows on the disk as if its only that OS on the disk and nothing else.

I know that I can do the same if I have two physical disks and both of them have bootable partitions. Then I'm able to simply select the OS by pressing the `F9`. But on a single disk?

Basically my dilemmas can be broken down into two questions:

1. Can I have multiple OSes on the same disk without a dual boot loader so that I could use `F9` to select which one to boot?
2. What and how do I use the *Boot from file* option in the `F9` BIOS boot menu?

Comment: Could you define "a dual boot loader"?

Comment: @user1686 when you install Linux on a Windows machine it asks you to install as dual boot. And when you do that it installs a dual boot loader as initial boot where you can then select your OS of choice of the dual boot.

Comment: I see what you mean, though I don't think I've ever heard it being called that. (The thing is that the same piece of software that shows the OS menu is also the _actual_ Linux boot loader; it's not just installed specifically for dual boot purposes.)

Comment: Does your F9 menu only list disks, or does it also list a "Windows Boot Manager" as a separate item? If you open diskmgmt.msc does it show an "EFI System Partition" on the Windows disk? Is the operating system Windows 10 or something older, and is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: My guess is this is an easy way to boot from an image like an iso of a live-distro. they don't ship optical disks anymore, and prepping a usb for boot is a pain, so being able to drop an iso on a normal usb stick and arbitrarily boot from it would be a much simpler way to boot into an image.

Comment: @user1686 It's Windows 10 x64 Pro. It does have the EFI partition as well as the Restore partition. Like any normal Win installation. I don't know how that specific *linux boot loader* is called. The thing is if you have just one system on your machine, no selection boot loader is being displayed, but if you install the second OS (i.e. Linux) it will add that, so that you always have to choose an OS when cold booting a machine.

Comment: Both MBR type partitions have special physical locations on disk where the BIOS/UEFI can find the bootloader for a given disk. so linux just installs the Grub boot-loader in this predictable location, and configures it to launch either the boot sector of the linux or windows OS.  If windows supported booting linux from its boot loader, it wouldn't matter which one of the two was used (bit as it is, linux will boot windows, not vice-versa). UEFI systems with GPT partitions have a boot manager that can boot any given partition, if the OS supports UEFI boot.